# Listing the certificate chain provided by a server on SSL_connect

Tags: security, sockets, visual-c++, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm new to security so some of the terms might be used incorrectly:

- When I create a socket connection using `SSL_connect`, the server should send back the entire certificate chain so that the authenticity of the server can be verified.
- For this to happen, the server needs to be configured accordingly.
- If the server doesn't send back the entire certificate chain and the intermediate certificate isn't in the client certificate store, the authenticity can't be verified. This results in the behavior experienced [here](https://superuser.com/questions/452063/the-certificate-is-not-trusted-because-no-issuer-chain-was-provided) in which FireFox regards a website as unsafe.
- I've also read that [some browsers are able to attain the intermediate certificate automatically](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-certificate-not-trusted-error.html). However, OpenSSL doesn't behavior like this, at least by default.
- I've also been told that some (maybe all) intermediate certificates have been installed in Windows certificate stores since some Windows update was rolled out a few years ago.

I would like to view the certificates returned by the server to verify that I'm getting back the entire certificate chain. Here's what I've tried:

- I'm using `SSLv3_method`.
- `SSL_CTX_set_verify` is set using `SSL_VERIFY_NONE`.
- After `SSL_connect` I use `SSL_get_peer_cert_chain` to get access to the certificate chain.

Consider:

```
STACK_OF(X509)* certificateChain = SSL_get_peer_cert_chain(ssl);
while (char* stackCertificate = sk_pop(certificateChain))
{
  X509* certificate = (X509*)stackCertificate;
}
```

Is this the correct way to get the certificate chain? Is my understanding of the situation correct? Is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Thank you for your time and contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet is based off code in `s_client`:

```
SSL* ssl = ...;
STACK_OF(X509)* certCollection = SSL_get_peer_cert_chain(ssl);
for (size_t i = 0; i < sk_X509_num(certCollection); i++)
{
  X509* cert = sk_X509_value(certCollection, i);
  ...
}
```

As far as I understand, an SSL session must have been created otherwise `SSL_get_peer_cert_chain` will return null. Additionally I haven't found any evidence to contradict the list I noted in my question.

Perhaps an easier alternative would be to use the command line tool (downloaded from [here](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)):

```
openssl s_client -connect {server}:{port} -ssl3
```